# How to copy one certificate root file to all Teamcity agents?

Tags: teamcity

Trying to copy one cert file to over 30 Teamcity agent servers.
Is there anyway Teamcity build step can achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the cert file into your Version Control System. (ie: into .cert folder)
2. Create a build Configuration to Copy this.
3. Add a command line build step

   ```
   copy ./cert/cerf.file C:\PathToCopy\cert.file
   ```
4. Inside the Run Custom Build (`...` next to [run] button, at the bottom of Agent list, select: `<All enabled compatible agents>`